# ssh with config not working but ssh with full command line works

Tags: linux, ssh

Just to clarify: the error I'm getting is not related with ssh files permissions. I'm not getting an error related with permissions.

I've the following ~/.ssh/config file

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  User APKAIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

config and id_rsa files have the following permissions

```
-rw------- 1 jmsanzg jmsanzg   93 jun 24 16:23 config
-rw------- 1 jmsanzg jmsanzg 1679 abr 26  2015 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 jmsanzg jmsanzg  396 abr 26  2015 id_rsa.pub
```

.ssh directory has the following permissions

```
drwx------  2 jmsanzg jmsanzg      4096 jun 24 16:23 .ssh
```

If I execute ssh forcing it to use the certificate and then it works

```
jmsanzg@jmsanz:~$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa APKAIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
You have successfully authenticated over SSH. You can use Git to interact with AWS CodeCommit. Interactive shells are not supported.Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
Connection to git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com closed.
```

But whenever I try to execute it directly trying to use the config file it fails

```
jmsanzg@jmsanz:~$ ssh git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Also if I set the user, just making tries to find why it fails, well, it fails too

```
jmsanzg@jmsanz:~$ ssh APKAIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This is driving me crazy because it worked like a charm since 2015 and yesterday sudendly stopped working without making (I think so) any change.
I've tried the -v parameter on both and I cannot see any specific difference. Just at the end, the command line offers the RSA public key

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/jmsanzg/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-256 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

while the other command line that should use the config file is not offering the file /home/jmsanzg/.ssh/id_rsa

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

**EDIT**
To make things more interesting. I've copied config, id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files to another computer. Gave the same permissions and...they work both ways, using config and with the full command line.

Comment: Try two `-v` parameters, or three. Try also the `-G` option (if your SSH client is new enough) to check if the configuration is being read.

Comment: @user1686 The configuration is being read because one of the outputs is debug1: Authenticating to git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:22 as 'APKAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, ec2 and everything.  When running `ssh host-name -v` I'd get `connection timed out`.  I tried:

- opening permissions on ec2 ssh inbound
- opening chmod permissions on .pem (can't do that, must be 400)
- simplifying key name

Finally, I just double checked my HostName and it was the wrong ec2 instance.  Also, there are multiple .ssh/config locations:

- /etc/ssh/ssh_config
- ~/.ssh/config

Mine is working now with correct ec2 instance:

- cwd = ~
- config loc = ~/.ssh/config
- config file

```
Host terraria
    HostName "###-###-##-##-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/"Terraria Key.pem"
```

- `ssh terraria`